# How to Store an YEAR from DatePickerDialog in Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

So basically i want to get the year from the user using the datePickerDialog and then substract that year to the current year. Till this i have no issues.
The problem is i have button created and want users to get a Toast message if they haven't chosen the date. I am using **if else** and validating the Year when the datePicker is not selected.
Also the year i am getting after the datePickerDialog is the current year.

Here is the Code -

```
 fun birthdayPicker() {

    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    val year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    val month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    val date = cal.get(Calendar.DATE)

    val textcheck : TextView = findViewById(R.id.yourage)

 val dateSelected = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_view_date_1)
    dateSelected.setOnClickListener {
        val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(
            this,
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { _, myear, mmonth, mdayOfMonth ->
                dateSelected.setText("" + mdayOfMonth + "/" + mmonth + "/" + myear)
                //        Toast.makeText(this, "$myear", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

           },
            year,
            month + 1,
            date
        )
        datePickerDialog.show()
    }
    val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_date_1)
    button.setOnClickListener {
        val selectedyear : Int = year
        if (selectedyear.toString().isBlank()) {
            Log.e("Main","$selectedyear")
            Toast.makeText(this, "Choose an Year", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        else {
            val checkingYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)
           textcheck.text = (checkingYear - selectedyear).toString()

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so you just store that into a variable as so

```
        val myFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy" //mention the format you need
        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US)
        val currentDate = sdf.format(cal.getTime())
```

Comment: Well, thank for the help...i will try this for sure